# What does "can't become lost" mean?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, travel

The Natural Explorer trait from the [UA Revised Ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) provides the following benefit (among others) when traveling for an hour or more:

> Your group can't become lost except by magical means.

The [PHB version of the feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#NaturalExplorer) provides the same benefit but only while in the ranger's favored terrain.

Does this mean that if I leave a stick in the woods, I can't fail to get back to the spot where I left it? Or does it mean I can vaguely keep on the correct path in order to find the village on the other side of that forest? Or something in between?

I can't see any rules either way, so as far as I can tell this is up to DM interpretation, but I am curious if there is anything missing (Possibly as part of another trait or spell) that will provide clarification.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What the Ranger feature talks about is also mentioned in the Navigate activity from p. 183 in the PHB:

> Navigate. The character can try to prevent the group from becoming lost, making a Wisdom (Survival) check when the DM calls for it. (The Dungeon Master’s Guide has rules to determine whether the group gets lost.)

The mentioned rules are in p. 111 from the DMG, under "Becoming Lost" section. I'm not sure I can paste the whole section here (copyright and all), but the relevant parts:

> Unless they are following a path, or something like it, adventurers traveling in the wilderness run the risk of becoming lost.

It then describes the test, the DC and all that stuff.

> If the Wisdom (Survival) check succeeds, the party
>   travels in the desired direction without becoming lost.
>   If the check fails, the party inadvertently travels in the
>   wrong direction and becomes lost. The party's navigator
>   can repeat the check after the party spends 1d6 hours
>   trying to get back on course.

So, essentially, having the Ranger in the party means you don't have to make this check, ever, because you can't get lost (i.e. you always succeed on this check).

---

As request by the asker, **what does count as a destination?** - first, it's not a game-defined word, so it just uses the common dictionary meaning.

> the place to which someone or something is going or being sent.

Any place that fits this descriptions works. The example given - 'the tree I buried the treasure under' - surely counts as a destination in my interpretation. It's ultimately up to the DM, though.

Comment: Thanks. This is good (And what I expected) but I will leave it a while in case someone finds something obscure before accepting it.

Comment: "Destination" doesn't appear in any of your quotes, so how is it related to becoming lost?

Comment: @SeriousBri Is there some other section of the rules that mentions "destination", or did you read "direction" as "destination"?

Comment: @NotThatGuy I gathered that this is based off the mention of "the desired direction" in the last quote.  Traveling without a goal, or a "destination" in mind is probably a clear indicator that you're already lost.

Comment: I'd note, significantly, that finding your precise destination and being lost are definitely two different things. You can know where you are, and where you are going, but still not be going where you meant to go. E.G, I see no reasonable interpretation of this that means the Ranger has a perfect ability to find any place they've been before no matter how well they do or do not remember it. Only that they wouldn't get lost trying to get back there.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil [Not all those who wander are lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_that_is_gold_does_not_glitter)

Comment: The ranger's feature does not allow you ro unneeringly go to a desired destination like a homing missile.  it allows you to go in the direction you choose (north east, etc..)  If you want to go to a village north of the forest you better know its exact location by heart else this skill will not help you.  you wont be lost (you know you are going north)  but you wont reach the village either becasue you have no clue where it is exactly.